# await using not working in net standard 2

Tags: c#, .net-standard-2.0

I have an issue I can't solve, I have a library with this definition

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;netstandard2.1;netcoreapp3.1;net5.0;net6.0;net7.0</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.0' ">
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

And after a http call with HttpClient I try to do this :

```cs
await using var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
```

Which produce this error :

> [CS8417] 'Stream': type used in an asynchronous using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IAsyncDisposable' or implement a suitable 'DisposeAsync' method. Did you mean 'using' rather than 'await using'?

The issue is clearly with NETSANDARD2_0, if I remove it, it works well.

I don't understand why it fails, as I have added the Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.

Comment: `Stream` does not implement `IAsyncDisposable` in .NET Standard 2.0, as `IAsyncDisposable` isn't part of .NET Standard 2.0. This is true whether or not you pull in `Bcl.AsyncInterfaces`, because that merely adds support for using it on new scenarios -- packages cannot retroactively weld new interfaces to existing types.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that in .NET Standard 2.0, `Stream` doesn't implement `IAsyncDisposable`.

It's entirely feasible to use `await using` within a .NET Standard 2.0 project *if* you're using types that actually implement `IAsyncDisposable` - although you also need to specify a `LangVersion` in the project file, as otherwise the *default* version of C# is used, which is 7.3 for .NET Standard 2.0. For example:

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Test
{
    static async void TestAwaitUsing()
    {
        // This is fine
        await using var working = new Sample();

        // This fails, because MemoryStream doesn't implement IAsyncDisposable
        await using var failing = new MemoryStream();
    }

    class Sample : IAsyncDisposable
    {
        public ValueTask DisposeAsync()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Project file:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Now it's entirely possible that in whatever platform the code is *running* on, `Stream` does actually implement `IAsyncDisposable` - but it's hard to make use of that in an elegant way.

For example, this compiles and will do the right thing if the application platform supports it:

```cs
await using var awkward = (IAsyncDisposable) new MemoryStream();
var stream = (MemoryStream) awkward;
// Now use things from stream
```

This will throw `InvalidCastException` if you're running on a platform which *doesn't* support it, however. If you can possibly change your target to .NET Standard 2.1 or a more recent one (e.g. .NET 6) that would be better. If you *actually* need to run your code with .NET Framework, you just won't be able to use `await using` with `Stream`.

Comment: And, of course, it will hard crash if the platform *doesn't* support it -- which is likely if you're trying to use .NET Standard 2 as a way to target .NET Framework, so not a good idea. :P If you only want to target platforms that support it, targeting those explicitly rather than using .NET Standard is a better idea.

Comment: @JeroenMostert: Added a note about this. I can imagine some weird situations where this is hard to avoid, but I agree it's best not to :)

Answer (score 3):

`await using` has been added in C# 8. The default C# version for netstandard2.0 is C# 7.3. In netstandard2.1 it is C# 8.

Comment: The language version and the .NET Standard spec are two different things. There is a relationship in feature support when it comes to types and runtime support, but it is not true that one enables the other. C# support is offered by the compiler, not whatever framework you're targeting.

Comment: No, this isn't a language version limitation beyond the default version associated with .NET Standard 2.0.

Comment: Even after the edit, this doesn't actually explain the error the OP is seeing. (My guess is that their project file specifies a LangVersion somewhere.)